# Blueprint Animation material - 3ds Max 2010

Tags: animation, 3dsmax

I would like to do Blueprint Animation in 3ds max and I have problem with material. It looks like this:

[Watch from 3:43](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUGe0X0lK3g)

Could give me an idea how can I do material like this on the movie or maybe do you know where I can download something like this?

I use 3ds Max 2010 and MentalRay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a MentalRay contour shader. For more info see [the manual here](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/3ds-Max-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-797FBC38-E08E-41DF-9D02-5C455B7C76E1.htm,topicNumber=d30e429918).